# Multi-Table Hierarchy Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I am trying to create a hierarchical query in SQL Server.

I have 4 tables:

- org3 (org3_id, org3_name)
- org4 (org4_id, org4_name, org4_org3id)
- org5 (org5_id, org5_name, org5_org4id)
- org6 (org6_id, org6_name, org6_org5id)

`Org3` is the highest level and org 6 is the lowest. As you can see org6 has a parent id in the org5 table, which has a parent id in the org4 table, which has a parent id in the org3 table.

It is possible for a parent to not have any children.

So say I have these values in the tables:

**Org3** table

```
| org3_id | org3_name |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | MS        |
| 2       | NS        |
```

**Org4** table

```
| org4_id | org4_name | org4_org3id |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| 1       | TS        | 1           |
| 2       | QS        | 1           |
| 3       | BS        | 1           |
```

**Org5** table

```
| org5_id | org5_name | org5_org4id |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| 1       | LS        | 1           |
| 2       | PS        | 1           |
| 3       | VS        | 2           |
```

**Org6** table

```
| org6_id | org6_name | org6_org5id |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| 1       | AS        | 1           |
| 2       | RS        | 1           |
| 3       | ZS        | 2           |
```

The result I would like to get is:

```
| org3_id | org3_name | org4_id | org4_name | org5_id | org5_name | org6_id | org6_name | path        |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|-------------|
| 1       | MS        | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | MS          |
| 1       | MS        | 1       | TS        | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | MS\TS       |
| 1       | MS        | 1       | TS        | 1       | LS        | NULL    | NULL      | MS\TS\LS    |
| 1       | MS        | 1       | TS        | 1       | LS        | 1       | AS        | MS\TS\LS\AS |
| 1       | MS        | 1       | TS        | 1       | LS        | 2       | RS        | MS\TS\LS\RS |
| 1       | MS        | 1       | TS        | 2       | PS        | NULL    | NULL      | MS\TS\PS    |
| 1       | MS        | 1       | TS        | 2       | PS        | 3       | ZS        | MS\TS\PS\ZS |
| 1       | MS        | 2       | QS        | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | MS\QS       |
| 1       | MS        | 2       | QS        | 3       | VS        | NULL    | NULL      | MS\QS\VS    |
| 1       | MS        | 3       | BS        | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | MS\BS       |
| 2       | NS        | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | NS          |
```

This is what I have tried.

```
SELECT 
    org3.org3_id,
    org3.org3_name,
    org3.org3_open_ind,
    org4.org4_id,
    org4.org4_name,
    org4.org4_open_ind,
    org5.org5_id,
    org5.org5_name,
    org5.org5_open_ind,
    org6.org6_id,
    org6.org6_name,
    org6.org6_open_ind,
    CONCAT(org3.org3_abbrv, '\', org4.org4_abbrv, 
           CASE
              WHEN org5.org5_abbrv IS NULL THEN ''
              ELSE CONCAT('\', org5.org5_abbrv)
           END, 
           CASE
              WHEN org6.org6_abbrv IS NULL THEN ''
              ELSE CONCAT('\', org6.org6_abbrv)
           END) AS [ORG PATH]                       
FROM 
    (SELECT
         *
     FROM
         TSTAFFORG3 
     WHERE
         org3_open_ind = 1) org3
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         *
     FROM
         TSTAFFORG4 
     WHERE
         org4_open_ind = 1) org4 ON org4.org4_org3id = org3.org3_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         *
     FROM
         TSTAFFORG5
     WHERE
         org5_open_ind = 1) org5 ON org5.org5_org4id = org4.org4_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         *
     FROM 
         TSTAFFORG6
     WHERE
         org6_open_ind = 1) org6 ON org6.org6_org5id = org5.org5_id
ORDER BY
    org3.org3_name, org4.org4_name, org5.org5_name, org6.org6_name
```

I think maybe a CTE query is needed, but I am not sure how to frame it in this case. If it was all in one table I think I could figure it out, but because it is multiple tables, I am having trouble figuring out the SQL. The query I tried doesn't show just the parent. It will only show where results where org3 has children.

Comment: What's wrong with the query you tried?   Did you get an error or unexpected results?

Comment: No, error, but like mentioned in my post, the result is not what is expected.  It didnt have a separate row for each parent.  It would only have lines 2 through 10 in my expected results.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution but I'm not how it would perform. It's basically adding an empty row to all levels.

```
        SELECT 
                org3.org3_id,
                org3.org3_name,
                org3.org3_open_ind,
                org4.org4_id,
                org4.org4_name,
                org4.org4_open_ind,
                org5.org5_id,
                org5.org5_name,
                org5.org5_open_ind,
                org6.org6_id,
                org6.org6_name,
                org6.org6_open_ind,
                CONCAT
                    (
                        org3.org3_name, 
                        '\' + org4.org4_name, 
                        '\' + org5.org5_name, 
                        '\' + org6.org6_name
                    )   AS [ORG PATH]                       
        FROM TSTAFFORG3 org3
        CROSS APPLY 
                (
                    SELECT  org4_id, org4_name, org4_open_ind, org4_org3id
                    FROM    TSTAFFORG4 
                    WHERE   org4_open_ind = 1
                    AND     org4_org3id = org3.org3_id
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, org3.org3_id
                ) org4 
                CROSS APPLY
                (
                    SELECT  org5_id, org5_name, org5_open_ind, org5_org4id
                    FROM    TSTAFFORG5
                    WHERE   org5_open_ind = 1
                    AND     org5_org4id = org4.org4_id
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, org4.org4_id
                ) org5 
                OUTER APPLY
                (
                    SELECT  org6_id, org6_name, org6_open_ind, org6_org5id
                    FROM    TSTAFFORG6
                    WHERE   org6_open_ind = 1
                    AND     org6_org5id = org5.org5_id
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, org4.org4_id
                ) org6 
                    WHERE
                            org3_open_ind = 1
        ORDER BY
                org3.org3_name, org4.org4_name, org5.org5_name, org6.org6_name;
```

In case someone else has a different idea, I'm leaving the sample data in a consumable format.

```
CREATE TABLE TSTAFFORG3( 
 org3_id    int,
 org3_name  varchar(10),
 org3_open_ind  bit);

 INSERT INTO TSTAFFORG3 
 VALUES
    ( 1, 'MS', 1),
    ( 2, 'NS', 1);

CREATE TABLE TSTAFFORG4( 
 org4_id    int,
 org4_name  varchar(10),
 org4_org3id    int,
 org4_open_ind  bit);

 INSERT INTO TSTAFFORG4
 VALUES
    ( 1, 'TS', 1, 1),
    ( 2, 'QS', 1, 1),
    ( 3, 'BS', 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE TSTAFFORG5( 
 org5_id    int,
 org5_name  varchar(10),
 org5_org4id    int,
 org5_open_ind  bit);

 INSERT INTO TSTAFFORG5
 VALUES
    ( 1, 'LS', 1, 1),
    ( 2, 'PS', 1, 1),
    ( 3, 'VS', 2, 1);

CREATE TABLE TSTAFFORG6( 
 org6_id    int,
 org6_name  varchar(10),
 org6_org5id    int,
 org6_open_ind  bit);

 INSERT INTO TSTAFFORG6
 VALUES
    ( 1, 'AS', 1, 1),
    ( 2, 'RS', 1, 1),
    ( 3, 'ZS', 2, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for putting it in a consumable format.  Ill have to remember to do that the next time I ask a question.  Also, that seems to work.  Not sure if it is the proper way, but it works, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear: You're modelling hierarchical data. There are a number of ways of storing hierarchical data in a RDBMS. Two are:

1. Adjacency lists (e.g. self-referential tables)
2. Materialized paths (e.g. `TS/MS/RS`).

Your data model seems problematic: If you wanted to add another level, would you add a new table?

If you are able to, you should move everything into one table:

`orgs(org_id, org_name, parent_org)`

This uses the adjacency list approach.

Then you could create a simple recursive CTE (or a number of self-joins) to get the materialized path.

Eschewing the Org ID (which would have to be regenerated if you put everything in one table), the following query will give you the results below:

```
WITH 
    -- sample data (I'm only using org names, not org IDs).
    Orgs(org_name, parent_org) AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            VALUES
            ('MS', NULL),
            ('NS', NULL),
            ('TS', 'MS'),
            ('QS', 'MS'),
            ('BS', 'MS'),
            ('LS', 'TS'),
            ('PS', 'TS'),
            ('VS', 'QS'),
            ('AS', 'LS'),
            ('RS', 'LS'),
            ('ZS', 'PS')
        ) v(c1, c2)
    ),
    -- hierarchical/recursive CTE
    OrgsWithPath(org_name, parent_org, org_path) AS
    (
        SELECT org_name, parent_org, CAST(org_name AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        FROM Orgs
        WHERE parent_org IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT Orgs.org_name, Orgs.parent_org, OrgsWithPath.org_path + '\' + Orgs.org_name
        FROM OrgsWithPath
            INNER JOIN Orgs ON
                Orgs.parent_org = OrgsWithPath.org_name
    )

SELECT * FROM OrgsWithPath ORDER BY org_path
```

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
| org_name | parent_org |  org_path   |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| MS       | NULL       | MS          |
| BS       | MS         | MS\BS       |
| QS       | MS         | MS\QS       |
| VS       | QS         | MS\QS\VS    |
| TS       | MS         | MS\TS       |
| LS       | TS         | MS\TS\LS    |
| AS       | LS         | MS\TS\LS\AS |
| RS       | LS         | MS\TS\LS\RS |
| PS       | TS         | MS\TS\PS    |
| ZS       | PS         | MS\TS\PS\ZS |
| NS       | NULL       | NS          |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Note the `ORDER BY` in the final `SELECT`: This determines whether your query is depth-first (traversing the full path) or breadth-first (starting with all the top-level nodes, then proceeding). With this approach, it's also trivial to include a "Level", so you know whether it's a top-level node or some other level.

Getting the additional columns is a bit trickier, but can also be handled by the recursive CTE (using `CASE`and `COALESCE`):

```
WITH 
    OrgsWithPath(org_name, org_path, org_level, org3_name, org4_name, org5_name, org6_name) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            Orgs.org_name, 
            CAST(org_name AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
            1,
            Orgs.org_name, 
            CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(255)), 
            CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(255)), 
            CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(255))
        FROM Orgs
        WHERE parent_org IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            Orgs.org_name,
            OrgsWithPath.org_path + '\' + Orgs.org_name,
            OrgsWithPath.org_level + 1,
            OrgsWithPath.org3_name,
            CASE WHEN OrgsWithPath.org_level+1 >= 2 THEN COALESCE(OrgsWithPath.org4_name, Orgs.org_name) END,
            CASE WHEN OrgsWithPath.org_level+1 >= 3 THEN COALESCE(OrgsWithPath.org5_name, Orgs.org_name) END,
            CASE WHEN OrgsWithPath.org_level+1 >= 4 THEN COALESCE(OrgsWithPath.org6_name, Orgs.org_name) END
        FROM OrgsWithPath
            INNER JOIN Orgs ON
                Orgs.parent_org = OrgsWithPath.org_name
    )

SELECT *
FROM OrgsWithPath 
ORDER BY org_path
```

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| org_name |  org_path   | org_level | org3_name | org4_name | org5_name | org6_name |
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| MS       | MS          |         1 | MS        | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
| BS       | MS\BS       |         2 | MS        | BS        | NULL      | NULL      |
| QS       | MS\QS       |         2 | MS        | QS        | NULL      | NULL      |
| VS       | MS\QS\VS    |         3 | MS        | QS        | VS        | NULL      |
| TS       | MS\TS       |         2 | MS        | TS        | NULL      | NULL      |
| LS       | MS\TS\LS    |         3 | MS        | TS        | LS        | NULL      |
| AS       | MS\TS\LS\AS |         4 | MS        | TS        | LS        | AS        |
| RS       | MS\TS\LS\RS |         4 | MS        | TS        | LS        | RS        |
| PS       | MS\TS\PS    |         3 | MS        | TS        | PS        | NULL      |
| ZS       | MS\TS\PS\ZS |         4 | MS        | TS        | PS        | ZS        |
| NS       | NS          |         1 | NS        | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: The problem with putting them all in one table is that the tables themselves are look up tables in my application.  So ill have cascading dropdowns for each org level

Comment: The application behavior need not rely on the database structure. You could create 4 separate views from the same table (even name them the same as they're named now) that the application uses.

Comment: @dk96m: Updated the query to include the additional columns.